# Will Allah forgive me for wishing someone's marriage break?

Tags: allah

I asked this question already. I am again disturbing you guys and i am sorry for that. But i just can't get peace in my mind. So i am telling my problem again.I was only 11-12 years old back than. There was an actor i liked. But he was married. He got married in January 7, 2013. I asked for his divorce. I used to make dua for it. I made the dua for about a month, like till 30th January 2013. But after some time i stopped doing that. They eventually got divorced in 2017. I somehow found myself guilty. I stopped making such dua way before their divorce. Will Allah punish me for that? Will my marriage to my husband break as well? Please reply..

Answer (score 0):

"Tell them(O Prophet)," My servants who have committed excesses against themselves (committed sins) do not lose hope in Allah's mercy. Surely Allah forgives all sins(with repentance). He is the most forgiving most merciful."(39:53)
Don't worry, Allah will forgive you, if you repent, everyone does mistakes but the best of them is the one who repents. You are sorry for this, so Allah will not punish you, he is very merciful.